# What is the analytical definition of the tangent function?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

In baby Rudin, the sine function is defined as $\frac{1}{2i} \left[\exp (ix) - \exp (-ix)\right]$, and the cosine function is defined as $\frac{1}{2}\exp (ix) + \frac{1}{2}\exp (-ix)$. In such a framework, how do we usually define the tangent function? Is it just $\sin/\cos$?

Comment: Yes, $\tan(z) = \sin(z)/\cos(z)$, whenever $\cos(z) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straightforward substitution:

$$\tan (x) = \frac{e^{i x}-e^{-i x}}{i \left(e^{-i x}+e^{i x}\right)}$$